# what are parameter and constants in orthogonal trajectories?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Also, in solving for orthogonal trajectories, why is it necessary to write the parameter and constant in terms of x and y and eliminate the parameter and/or constant?

Answer (score 0):

"Orthogonal trajectories" refers to a collection of curves that are all orthogonal to ever curve in a given **family** of curves. That family of curves depends on some parameter that determines the particular curve in that family.  Since the "orthogonal trajectory" is a completely **different** collection of curves, that original parameter cannot be in the equation for these new curves.

Comment: I'm kinda getting what you are saying. Still it will be really good with an example if you can. Thank you.